# UICollectionView is not starting at the Y position 0 in iOS

Tags: ios

I have requirement of tapping on the screen the app should hide the status bar. I have added the Label at y Position as 0 and also collection view at y position 0 in story board. When I run the app, the label y position is zero only but the collection view is starting at Y position 20. Can anyone help me on this.

Comment: Did you set a constraint to top layout guide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uncheck adjust scroll view insets for that `UIViewController` in your storyboard.

[image]