# How do you set constraints for scrollview that doesn't occupy the whole parent view

Tags: ios, interface-builder, scrollview, ios-autolayout

I'm trying to build UI similar to that of ios photo gallery : Navigation view controller with a scrollview occupying 80% height and 100% width of the parent's view and the collection view controller occupying the rest of the height and 100% width. So here's how it looks like :

[image]

The blue area is scrollview and its content view. The bottom part is a collection view which suppose to behave like a carousel. You can see the constraints that I have set in the following screenshot :

[image] :

I want to set the scrollview height so that it only occupies 80% of the parent view estate and the collection view occupies the rest. However, I can't seem to resolve scrollview constraint issues such as autolayout not able to resolve height/y position of scrollview. As you can see in the above pic, I tried setting the height of the scrollview to 50% of the parent view but the autolayout still complains about not being able to resolve height. If I let interface builder resolve the issue, it just adds spacing to the content view inside scrollview and pushes it down as a result. You can see that in the following screenshots.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your view heirarchy is correctly setup so thats quite nice and you are on the right track of what constraints to add. I'm going to write all the constraints starting from step 1.

- To your `UIScrollView` add a top, leading and trailing constraint to the `superView`. Also add a equal height constraint between your `UIScrollView` and the `superView` and set the multiplier to 0.8.
- Now add  your `UICollectionView` below the `UIScrollView` and give it a leading, trailing and bottom to the `superView`. Also add a vertical spacing between the `UICollectionView` and `UIScrollView`.
- Now add for the *contentView* inside the `UIScrollView`. Add a leading, top, bottom and trailing for the *contentView* to `UIScrollView`. As soon as you do this, the constraints will break and Xcode will complain. **Now** what you need to do more is add a equal height and width constraint between the `UIScrollView` and *contentView*. Set the priority of this equal height constraint (assuming you want vertical scroll) to something like 250, so that it breaks when the content inside the `UIScrollView` becomes too large to be displayed completely.

Now as far as that extra spacing issue is concerned. What you need to do is, select the `UIViewController` that has your `UIScrollVIew` and then select the attributes inspector for this `UIViewController` and **uncheck** the *adjust scroll view insets* option. For a screenshot, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41036854/4539192).

[image]

Comment: I wasn't expecting such a comprehensive a reply. Thank you so much for this! And I've never used priority before, and your reply taught me something new. Thanks for that as well.

Answer (score 1):

As i see from above do the following.

1. Add leading, trailing and top constraint to scrollview.
2. Add height constraint i.e drag from scrollview to superview and add equal width, in equal width constraint change the multiple factor to 0.8.
3. Add leading trailing, bottom constraint to collection view with respect to superview and vertical space constraint with respect to scrollview.